# Alternative for Cross Apply() in SQL

Tags: sql, join, presto, cross-apply

How can the below SQL query written using JOIN? I'm trying to convert SQL script to Trino/Presto and this does not support Cross Apply().

```
 select i.*,k.*

  FROM dbo.[LN] i
  CROSS APPLY(select top 1 * from
  dbo.[LN]  j
  where i.vnd_nbr = j.vnd_nbr and i.cltstyle = j.cltstyle and j.compdate > i.compdate order by compdate
  ) k order by i.VND_NBR
```

Comment: Top 1 means you have multiple rows, but a Top without an order makes noch much sense

Comment: @nbk order by **compdate** will be fine

Comment: @AaronBertrand eventually it does, as I'm currently working with handful of records only.

Comment: @AaronBertrand definitely not. Currently I'm in process of migrating the SQL script to Trino/Presto, but sadly it does not support Cross Apply().

Comment: @AaronBertrand reaaly not sure. There are many SQL methods which are not supported in Trino/Presto.. always have to find a work around in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

As you have a system that does not suport `CROSS APPLY`

xou can use a CTE for that purpüose

```
WITH CTE AS(
 select i.*,k.*,
 ROW_NUMBBER() OVER (PARTITION BY k.vnd_nbr,k.cltstyle, k.compdate ORDER BY k.compdate) en
  FROM dbo.[LN] i
  JOIN 
  dbo.[LN]  k
  ON i.vnd_nbr = k.vnd_nbr and i.cltstyle = k.cltstyle and k.compdate > i.compdate
  )  
  SELECT * FROM 
  CTE
  WHERE rn = 1
  order by VND_NBR
```