# Refactor SQL code without using Outer Apply

Tags: sql

I have SQL code below, I need to refactor it using LEFT JOIN, but not OUTER APPLY. Could you please help me with that?

```
SELECT cur.downtimedataid,
          cur.serverid,
          cur.downtimestart,
          cur.downtimefinish,
          cur.downtimeinfo1,
          cur.downtimeinfo2,
          cur.newproductionorderid,
          cur.plantid,
          cur.workcenterid,
          cur.dm_plantid,
          PR.previousorderid

    FROM   bcs cur 
           /*Function to find Previous Order*/
           OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 prev.newproductionorderid AS PreviousOrderID,
                                prev.PlantID
                        FROM   bcs prev
                        WHERE  prev.serverid = cur.serverid
                               AND prev.workcenterid = cur.workcenterid
                               AND prev.downtimestart < cur.downtimefinish
                        ORDER  BY prev.downtimestart DESC) PR
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative for Cross Apply() in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73429602/alternative-for-cross-apply-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use correlated subquery:

```
SELECT cur.downtimedataid,
              cur.serverid,
              cur.downtimestart,
              cur.downtimefinish,
              cur.downtimeinfo1,
              cur.downtimeinfo2,
              cur.newproductionorderid,
              cur.plantid,
              cur.workcenterid,
              cur.dm_plantid,
              PR.previousorderid,
    (SELECT TOP 1 prev.newproductionorderid AS PreviousOrderID,
                                    prev.PlantID
                            FROM   bcs prev
                            WHERE  prev.serverid = cur.serverid
                                   AND prev.workcenterid = cur.workcenterid
                                   AND prev.downtimestart < cur.downtimefinish
                            ORDER  BY prev.downtimestart DESC
    ) as previousorderid
        FROM   bcs cur
```